# Get inserted id (node.js + mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sql-insert

I try to get id of user (auto increment id field) when insert data to user table. Here is ,my code:

```
  let sql = "INSERT into users(name, date, photo) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+date+"',  '"+photo+"')";
  connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        //console.log(error);
          res.status(500).json({message: "Invalid Request"});
      } else {
        let inserted_id = result.user_id; // undefined
        console.log(inserted_id);   
        res.status(200).json({message: ""});       
      }
  });
```

And when i try to print user_id i get undefined. Please help me.

Comment: Change `result.user_id` to `result.insertId` as shown in documentation: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

Answer (score 6):

`result.insertId` will give inserted id. Use it like this:

```
connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {

      } else {
          let inserted_id = result.insertId;
      }
 });
```

Comment: Great timing, this is the little tidbit I was missing to get my insert function finished.